# Filtering itertools combinations for dynamic number of constraints

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python program and function that returns a series of rows from my MySQL database. These returned rows are filtered by a set of IDs contained in a tuple, I then use itertools and list comprehension to form 'combinations' that conform to a fixed set of constraints (the attributes of each combination must be either "all equal" or "all unique" within that combination).

I'd like to make the function dynamic for different number of IDs but I'm not sure how to filter the returned rows dynamically (without a mess of nested IF statements). Is there a way I can re-write the if/and conditions in the function below to make them dynamic for len(tuple_of_ids)?

I'm very much still a learner when it comes to python/code development so any assistance would be appreciated!

My current (psuedo-) code:

```
import itertools

def get_valid_combinations(tuple_of_ids):

    data = get_filtered_data_from_database(valid_ids=tuple_of_ids)

    # (row1, row2, row3) assumes that the tuple_of_ids has len=3. If tuple_of_ids had 4 members I'd need (row1, row2, row3, row4) etc
    valid_combinations = [(row1, row2, row3) for row1, row2, row3 in list(itertools.combinations(data, 3))
                                if ((row1.Age == row2.Age)              # All items in combination have same Age
                                    and (row2.Age == row3.Age))

                                and ((row1.School != row2.School)
                                     and (row2.School != row3.School)
                                     and (row1.School != row3.School))      # All items in combination have different School
                ]
                # ...etc (i.e. there may be multiple filtering criteria, but always either ("all equal" or "all different")

    return valid_combinations

ids_to_search_for = ('C00001', 'C00002', 'C00003')
get_valid_combinations(tuple_of_ids = ids_to_search_for)

>>> [(<database_row_object_1>, <database_row_object_2>, <database_row_object_3>), (<database_row_object_x>, <database_row_object_y>, <database_row_object_z>),...]
```

Comment: Instead of filtering in Python, why not use `WHERE` filters *in the SQL query* and have the database do the filtering?

Comment: Otherwise, take a look at the `all()` and `any()` functions.

Comment: If you are only going to iterate over the combinations once, don't use `list(combinations)` that kills the efficiency.

Comment: Removing the list(...) is a good point, I'm not sure I could use WHERE clauses though - I probably didn't make it explicit in my original question (I've edited it now) but the output is a list of combinations that could use the same row in multiple tuples - I'm not sure how MySQL would return the same row in different groupings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martijn stated in the comment, you may look at doing the filtering in SQL, which is bound to be probably more efficient. If the filtering must be done in Python, the *"all equal" or "all different"* check could easily be done with a set comprehension:

```
length = len(tuple_of_ids)
valid_combinations = [tup for tup in itertools.combinations(data, length)
                              if len({r.Age for r in tup}) == 1
                              and len({r.School for r in tup}) == length]
```

The only overhead with doing this is that the sets are destroyed as soon as they are created, as only their lengths are needed.

On a side note, you can drop the *cast* to `list` for `itertools.combinations` since you don't actually need the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think that passing functions by reference is a pretty pythonic way of easily adding or removing constraints from your code. This is a contrived example:

```
#Just an example class
class Person(object):
    __slots__ = ["age","height","weight"]
    def __init__(self,age,height,weight):
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
​
#Function to try all tests
def test_people(people,tests):
    test_results = [test(people) for test in tests]
    print "Passed all tests:",all(test_results)
    print "Passed at least one:",any(test_results)

#Testing functions to be passed into the test_people
def first_lighter_than_second(people):
    p1 = people[0]
    p2 = people[1]
    return True if p1.weight < p2.weight else False
def third_older_than_first(people):
    p1 = people[0]
    p3 = people[2]
    return True if p3.age > p1.age else False
​
#Building people list
p1 = Person(24,182.1,90.5)
p2 = Person(50,170.4,83)
p3 = Person(62,150.3,67)
people = [p1,p2,p3]
​
#Building list of test functions
tests = []
tests.append(first_lighter_than_second)
tests.append(third_older_than_first)
​
#Try all tests
test_people(people,tests)

#Output
Passed all tests: False
Passed at least one: True
```

A downside is that you need to create lots of small functions and remember to add them to a list